# Problema com criação dinâmica de elementos

Tags: javascript, herança, protótipo

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que usa bastante Jquery, já que há varias funções bem específicas.

Mas por  motivos de personalização e otimização, consegui com a mistura de algumas pesquisas criar "minha própria lib" de modo bem simplista, nada demais, apenas com objetivo de executar funções no front-end que estilizem o site a partir de um padrão dele próprio. O link de uma parte dela [está aqui no gitHub](https://github.com/samirbraga/libM/blob/master/mlib.js).

E criei a função `.newElement()`, que no caso abaixo funciona perfeitamente.

```js
var div = M('div');
div.css({
  width: '100px',
  padding: '10px',
  background: "#333"
})

var a = div.newElement('a');
a.css({
  color: 'white'  
})
a.html('Exemplo')
a.attrs({
  href: "https://jsfiddle.net/",
  target: "_blank"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/samirbraga/libM/master/mlib.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Porém, quando tento criar mais de um filho ao mesmo elemento, tenho um problema:

```js
var div = M('div');
div.css({
  width: '100px',
  padding: '10px',
  background: "#333"
})

var a = div.newElement('a');
a.css({
  color: 'white'  
})
a.html('Exemplo')
a.attrs({
  href: "https://jsfiddle.net/",
  target: "_blank"
})

var p = div.newElement('p');
p.html('Texto que não deveria ser adicionado ao link')
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/samirbraga/libM/master/mlib.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

O novo filho, que pelo código deveria ser adicionado ao mesmo elemento, é adicionado ao filho. No caso fica `div > a > p`, o que deveria ser `div > a, p`.

O estranho é que caso eu não passe o elemento que eu queira adicionar para uma variável `div = M('div')` e ao invés disso use `M('div').newElement('p')`, **funciona**.

Não sei o que está causando isso.

O código da função `newElement()`:

```
newElement: function(element){
  var _newElement;
  each(self.myArg, function(el, i) {
    _newElement = document.createElement(element)
    el.appendChild(_newElement);
  })
  return M(_newElement)
},
```

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: O que é `self.myArg`?

Comment: @Sergio, é o argumento da função geral. `M('.div')`, no caso `.div` seria retornado no `self.myArg`.

Comment: Entretanto vi o link do Github, fui ver lá

Comment: Já é tarde aqui e não vou poder analizar muito. Mas qual é a ideia do `.myIndex`?

Comment: @Sergio, Seria um segundo argumento da função, seleciona o elemento pelo index. Ex `M('div', 2)`. Uso como outra opção para `M('div').eq(2)`.

Comment: Ok, e porque tens `var myArg;
  var self;` globais? Há um risco grande de serem sobreescritos por métodos em elementos diferentes...

Comment: @Sergio, isso é verdade. No caso, nem uso o `myArg`, mas uso o `self`. Como acha que deveria seguir?

Comment: Criar uma nova biblioteca é complexo. Se tens só alguns métodos, tudo bem. Senão é melhor usar algo que já exista. E há muita coisa por aí melhor que jQuery :P  Mas olha, fica aqui uma ideia da abordagem que poderias ter: https://jsfiddle.net/6883xzsh/

Comment: @Sergio, é já tive contato com algumas :P, a ideia nem era criar toda uma lib, eram só métodos próprios do app que estou criando, tipo replaces de selects, etc. O foco mesmo, era só substituição de elementos, por isso, o método que mais usaria era esse `newElement`. Vou dar uma olhada no seu fiddle.

Comment: @Sergio, dei uma olhada. É, no seu exemplo, com class e os contructors está funcionando bem. Mas ainda não consegui aplicar no meu, acho que o problema está no loop. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela atenção. :)